# 3D object transformation to match location

Tags: opencv, graphics, 3d, transformation

I have a  partial mesh (vertices and normals) of a 3d object in world coordinates and also the 3d Model of the object.

How can I **best** match the location and place the 3D model in place of the mesh?

I know how to match 2 point clouds using methods like ICP in opencv and open3d etc.,

However, I do not know how to go about with 3d objects. Could anyone give a pointer to this?

Comment: Naive comment : if you are able to reliably find for one vertex of the partial mesh to which vertex it corresponds in the 3d model then the rest is piece of cake ... So I suppose your problem is finding this correspondance right ?

Comment: The partial mesh is from a reconstruction so getting the correspondence right for one vertex is non trivial unfortunately. That is why I mentioned the "best" match.

Comment: Can't you "simply" construct a point cloud from partial mesh, another point cloud from the 3d model and use opencv's ICP to get the 'pose' (the 4x4 matrix to apply to the 3d model to match location of the partial mesh) ?
The point cloud for each would be just the list of vertices + normals (if this does not give you enough points you can also get more points for the 3d object by generating extra random points on the 3d model faces)

Comment: ICP also works in 3D !?

Comment: **best** is one of the most used and most meaningless term on SO.

Comment: @YvesDaoust not sure how else you want me to describe the problem .. happy to change the term if you think there is a better one..  By best here I mean, matching visually the best. ICP works in 3D but it requires points clouds tmk.

Comment: @VB_overflow that is one option, the long way around option.  I say long way around because I am doing this on iOS and mesh sampling on iOS is painful.

Comment: @PavanK: don't you tell us that you have vertices ?

Comment: vertices on the mesh are quite sparse often tbf

Comment: Would be better to explain us what your data looks like.

Comment: Ok I can try to add a visual, I will compile and post a sample image shortly

Comment: @PavanK: explanation in words isn't bad either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using ICP (point to point / point to plane methods) on two generated point clouds of 3D model and the partial mesh.

I generated one point cloud by re-sampling the 3D model and the second point cloud by re-sampling the partial mesh (libigl). I had to resample to have uniform number of points as ICP gave unstable results, if not.

Hope this helps someone.

P.S.: This was also suggested by @VB_overflow in the comments.